# position div center horizontal and vertical

Tags: css

i would like to center a popup div how can i do that browser friendly????

this is the original a bit to the left.

```
<div class="popLayerWrapper">
    <div id="addBookmarksLayer" class="popLayer" style="left:260px; padding:30px;">
        <div class="closeLayer" >close</div>
        <div class="layerContent"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand which part you want to center, but assuming the whole thing:

```
.popLayerWrapper {
   position: absolute;
   width: 40%;  /* could be anything */
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -20%;  /* half of width */
   height: 40%;    /* again, could be anything */
   top: 50%;
   margin-top: -20%;  /* half of height */
}
```

Comment: to make sure it's on top, you may want to put something like:
z-index: 10; in there too

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to center an element in the center of the window viewport:

```
html {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
}

body {  
  display: table-cell;  
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin:0;
}

#center {
  margin: auto;
}
```

You will find a full example at this link ([Bredele CSS bundle](https://github.com/bredele/css-bundle)). I think it should work for your popup.

Olivier