# CSS: Vertical and horizontally centered

Tags: html, css

Challenge: you have an empty body tag. Its only child is a div. The div's height and width are unknown. Make the contents of the div vertically and horizontally centered, using CSS/HTML alone (no JavaScript).

For a test sandbox, fork: http://jsfiddle.net/pB9hK/

Comment: Don't you mean 'whose height is not fixed'?

Comment: There are many solutions to this already on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D+vertical+horizontal+center

Comment: possible duplicate of [position div center horizontal and vertical](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726219/position-div-center-horizontal-and-vertical)

Comment: Do u need it with pure css or we can use a small line of jquery?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's an "ideal" cross-browser pure CSS solution for vertical-centering that's not more trouble than it's worth. If you want to use a single line of jQuery...

```
$('#adiv').css('marginTop', ($(window).height() - $('#adiv').height()) / 2);
```

CSS...

```
#adiv {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Comment: @Midas Your preferences on using straight Javascript or jQuery are irrelevant to validity of this solution.

Comment: I think jQuery is more irrelevant because it's not standard. You could also have used a pseudo code for this if you didn't want to use plain JS.

Answer (score 1):

For Horizontal use

```
body>div#center
{
text-align: center;
}
```

for Vertical use

```
body>div#center
   {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use display:table. You'll find an example at this link ([Bredele vertical centering](https://github.com/bredele/css-bundle/tree/master/vertical-centering)). Here a snippet I use:

```
html {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
}

body {  
  display: table-cell;  
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin:0;
}

#center {
  margin: auto;
}
```

As you asked, the height and width of div#center are unknown.

Olivier

Answer (score -4):

Here is a reply to wdm. A plain JavaScript version for vertical centering.

```
var el = document.getElementById('main');
el.style.marginTop = (document.body.offsetHeight - el.offsetHeight) / 2;
```

Comment: -1 for attitude. wdm's solution is as valid as yours. Focus on the question, not on the people answering it.